# dpdk testpmd could not open tx_iface

Tags: dpdk

i download dpdk 17.11.1 and configure hugepages and take the interface enp0s3 from kernel to dpdk and after that i tried to read packets from a pcap file and write them to a network interface with the command:

sudo testpmd -c '0x3' -n 4 --vdev 'eth_pcap0,rx_pcap=/home/my_username/nnn.pcap' --vdev 'eth_pcap1,iface=enp0s3' -- --port-topology=chained

(enp0s3 is dpdk interface)

the command based on this link (point 15.1.1.2):
http://dpdk.org/doc/guides-1.8/prog_guide/libpcap_ring_based_poll_mode_drv.html

when i used this command with kernel interface enp0s9 instead of enp0s3 i got crash,
and if i used enp0s3 i got this error:
PMD: Couldn't open enp0s3: enp0s3: SIOCETHTOOL(ETHTOOL_GET_TS_INFO) ioctl failed: No such device
PMD: Couldn't open interface enp0s3

maybe do you have an idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> take the interface enp0s3 from kernel to dpdk
>
> Couldn't open interface enp0s3

Since we took the `enp0s3` from the kernel and bound it to the UIO driver, there is no such interface in the kernel indeed.

If we take interfaces form the kernel, we cannot reference them with kernel names anymore. DPDK will probe those NICs automatically and match the corresponding PMDs.

So basically, we do not need the `--vdev 'eth_pcap1,iface=enp0s3'` option, the interface must appear in the `testpmd` without any options.